# MongoDB: How to retrieve the array that contains a specific value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have this schema:

```
user={ email:String,things:[],rules:[{name:String,devicesInvolved:[]} ]
```

I do not manage to retrieve all the users and rules, that contains a specific device involved in a rule.
For example, I want to retrieve all the users that in their rules, in their devices involved, contains a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

Use [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) to project just the matching element from the array

```
db.user.find({'rules.devicesInvolved':'device1'}, {email:1, 'rules.$':1})
```

---

Edit:

Above query will return only the first match. If you want all matching elements from the array then better use aggregates

```
db.user.aggregate(
  {$unwind: '$rules'},
  {$match: {'rules.devicesInvolved': 'device1'}},
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', rules: {$addToSet: '$rules'}}}
)
```

Comment: 'rules' is an array of objects, 'rules.$' returns only the first match

Comment: What I want is: For each user that has 'device1' in their 'devicesInvolved', I want to retrieve the 'things' and the 'rules' that matched

Comment: The query above returns nothing

Comment: share sample data and the output that you get. the above query won't give you `things`. you need to project it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gP5WtA4S
I want to retrieve: _id, things, and all the rules that contain in 'devicesInvolved' 'Bathroom Light'